# Unity-control-center segmentation fault

Tags: unity, system-settings, segmentation-fault

I cannot open the system settings anymore.

> unity-control-center
>
> (unity-control-center:23772): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: If this happens even after a reboot, I guess that the only thing you can do is to report this as a bug on Launchpad. There is already a [similar bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1562342). Did you just change your theme?

Comment: Welcome to the club. I'm guessing you've got an nvidia graphics card? Ubuntu MATE is likely going to be MORE stable than Unity very soon, if not already.

Comment: ANY workarounds?  Pretty basic problem!