# System settings not working

Tags: system-settings

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my Asus N550JK and everything seems to be working fine, except for the system settings. When I try to open the system settings, only the settings icon appears in the toolbar, it hangs for a while and then disappears without any error message. The same things happens when I try to open a specific section of the settings (e.g. "sound") **except** for the section "printers".

In advance, thank you.

Comment: Execute `unity-control-center` from a terminal, and look for any errors.

Comment: I just did it and I got the following error : "(unity-control-center:24476): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)" therefore this relates to this issue : http://askubuntu.com/questions/786927/unity-control-center-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which was solved just by installing "unity-control-center".

Comment: Already installed. `apt-get install --reinstall` didn't help either. :(